Does MySQL invalidate or amend a cached table when rows are added, updated or deleted?
What does MySQL (InnoDB) do when it has cached an entire table into memory and one or more rows in that table changes?
Does MySQL in this instance amend the cache in memory, or would it consider the cache dirty, dump the cached table data, and then re-cache the table the next time it is queried?

What version of MySQL or MariaDB are you using ???

Caching for InnoDB is at the block level (16KB), not the table level.  If you are tight on memory, it is likely to have blocks from several tables.

InnoDB is a journaled engine that allow transactions. Each write to the InnoDB-backed table is a single atomic transaction. When cached table is written, all changes are written to the journal first, then to the cached copy (as it used for reads), then to the disk, and finally changes are marked in the journal as commited. That guarantee the consistency of cached tables.
